# wxWidgets application freezes when trying to start new dialog

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm developing an wxWidgets application and I'm trying to create a callback which will show dialog given in my custom event class as a pointer to dynamicly created dialog object.
Reason for this is that I want a callback that will start any dialog/window not knowing the dialog exact class.

For this I need the dialog to be showed form main thread (e.g. callback function) otherwise program encounteres an error (in certain conditions it still runs, but notifies user it is not correct way of starting new windows).

So I create new dialog, assign it to my custom event and queue the event to the main window.

```
wxDialog *dialog = new TelemetryDialog(MainWindow::mInstance);
DialogEvent *event = new DialogEvent(EVENT_DIALOG_SHOW, dialog);
MainWindow::mInstance->m_eventHandler->QueueEvent(*event);
```

then in callback function:

```
wxDialog *dialog = event.getDialog();
if (dialog != NULL)
{
    dialog->Show(true);
}
```

And what happens is that dialog apperes empty and the program freezes.
But if I use callback function like that:

```
wxDialog *dialog = new TelemetryDialog(this);
dialog->Show();
```

it's just fine.
I have been thinking about cloning dialog object, but it's just imposible (copy constructor of a base class is private).

Did anybody tried something like this before? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that calling a dialog constructor in a worker thread is a no-no!

Whatever the exact problem, I would suggest doing all the GUI stuff in the main thread will be much safer.  Like this:

In your custom event, pass an enumerated integer.  Then, in your callback function, use a switch statement to construct and show the required dialog.

```
switch ( event.getDialogType() ) {
case TelemetryDialogType:
  dialog = new TelemetryDialog(MainWindow::mInstance);
  break;
...
}

dialog->Show(true);
```

Comment: That complicates things. Thank you.